# Ubuntu 22.04 autoinstall storage layout examples

Tags: autoinstall

When using autoinstall's LVM storage layout, how do I create custom LVM partitions using sizing-policy as with key scaled and value set to Between 10-20 GiB

```
storage:
  layout:
    name: lvm
```